# How do I connect to a postgres docker image with username, password, and url after running it?

Tags: java, windows, postgresql, docker

Basically, I'm following my school assignment. It says to run a postgres image locally as so `docker run --rm --name pg-docker -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker -p 5432:5432 postgres:11`. Then, it says I can connect to the database with the following info `username: postgres`, `password: docker`, `url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres`. I've tried looking online, but can't find ways to do this in my command prompt (I'm on Windows). I'm wondering if this can only be refered to the Java code that I'm supposed to eventually do?
Then it says I should create database and generate Jooq records:
`mvn clean package`. There's a folder with some yaml and sql files. However, when I run this command, there's always a build failure.

Comment: You need to write your java code. Or download something like [SQuirreL SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) if you just want to try it out. You will also need a postgres jdbc driver to connect.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1 (dockerized).**

Run

```
docker run --rm -it --net host postgres:11 psql -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432
```

and enter password `docker` when prompted.

**Option 2 (native).**

Download and install postgresql for windows from here: https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads

Then connect from PowerShell as following:

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432
```

and enter password `docker` when prompted.